# How do I add a customized parameter to image links

Tags: 8, entities, nodes, media

Lets say I have image fields in my node. When I get that fields values in the twig it returns the image URL without any issue.

```
file_url(node.field_image.entity.uri.value)
```

But now I want to add a specific parameter (lets say ?param=0) to the end of that link. Without hard coding the parameter in the twig file is there a way to write a hook that adds that parameter for all the image links in every node. So if I have to change the param I only need to change it from one place.

Comment: How is the image link created ? is it another field ? Link to itself as a bigger image ?

Comment: @GiorgosK No this is an normal image field in the node. I want to know how to add a param without putting it like `file_url(node.field_image.entity.uri.value)?param=0`. Is there a way to do this like globally. If I change from one place it should apply to all the images.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a preprocess function `THEMENAME_preprocess_field` and check whether the field is an image and it has a URL

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if($variables["element"]["#field_type"] == "image"){
    if(isset($variables["items"][0]["content"]["#url"])){
      $variables["items"][0]["content"]["#url"]->setOption('query', ['param' => '0']);
    }
  }
}
```